# Like statment read from result table to compare

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database there are articles. Example or articles below, as you see there is always main article (with .1 at the end) which could contain combinations (.+1) for next

```
1st article:
-------------------------------------------------------
12.3356.1 <- main artikel (1)
12.3356.2 <- sub artikel (2)
12.3356.3 <- sub artikel (3)

2nd article:
-------------------------------------------------------
4.641.1   <- main artikel (1)

3rd article:
-------------------------------------------------------
664.6241.1   <- main artikel (1)
664.6241.2   <- sub artikel (2)
664.6241.3   <- sub artikel (3)
664.6241.4   <- sub artikel (4)

4th article:
-------------------------------------------------------
7.31.1   <- main artikel (1)
7.31.2   <- sub artikel (2)
```

Now somwhere in my program i get some specific articles. Let's say:

```
12.3356.3
7.31.2
```

Now what i have to do is to take them and all rest associated within same number so in this case result would be as follows:

```
12.3356.1
12.3356.2
12.3356.3

7.31.1
7.31.2
```

so what i did so far is this:

```
;WITH cutted_nummers (cut_num) as (select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Nummer),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(Nummer)),len(Nummer))) from T_Artikel),
dist_nums (dist_num) as (select distinct(cut_num) from cutted_nummers),
final (nums) as (select dist_num from dist_nums) select * from final
```

so by this query i get those articles, then i am cutting last .digit out of those two articles so i got in final table:

```
12.3356.  (without 3 at the end)
7.31.     (without 2 at the end)
```

Now having this result i have to look to my artikel table and get all nummbers which start with one of those two and that's something i don't know how to do. I think i need like statment but how to say to LIKE from this result so this should look like:

```
select * from artikeltable that nummerfield is like '12.3356.%' or '7.31.%'
```

so like has to be constructed (in this case) based on two articles from 'final' table.

**EDIT for NEED:**

```
;WITH cutted_nummers (cut_num) as (select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Nummer),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(Nummer)),len(Nummer))) from T_Artikel),
dist_nums (dist_num) as (select distinct(cut_num) from cutted_nummers),
final (nums) as (select dist_num from dist_nums)
SELECT Nummer FROM T_Artikel
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(Nummer , 0, LEN(Nummer ) -  CHARINDEX(REVERSE(Nummer ), '.', 0)) IN 
    (
        SELECT nums FROM final
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @Tmp NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @Tmp = COALESCE(@Tmp, '') +  ' nummerfield LIKE ''' + ColumnName + '%'' OR' FROM final 

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)  = 'select * from artikeltable  WHERE ' + LEFT(@Tmp, LEN(@Tmp) - 3)
--SELECT @Query
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

By the way, you can find this way too.

```
DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(100) = '12.3356.2'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@val, 0, LEN(@val) + 2 -  CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@val))) -- 12.3356.
```

Update

Try this then

```
SELECT * FROM artikeltable
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(nummerfield , 0, LEN(nummerfield ) + 2 -  CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@val))) IN 
    (
        SELECT * FROM final
    )
```

Comment: is there other way? As i have to put all of tose queries into string and then place in my application and not directly into sql server so cannot use declare statment.

Comment: @JimmyJimm Updated.

Comment: can you look at my main post - i placed entire query - do you think it's good enough at all?

Comment: yes it works. by the way why this only: CHARINDEX(REVERSE(nummerfield ), '.', 0) always giving me 0 - always. Even if char is in the middle i get 0

Comment: i mean the part i mentioned always giving 0 i just did e.g: SELECT CHARINDEX(REVERSE(nummerfield ), '.', 0) FROM tableX where Nummer = '1.546.23' or whatever Nummer result for this part is always 0 so question is why i need this part? As i dont understand whyy '.' is not as first argument of function charindex

Comment: from my understanding we looking for reverted nummer within dot char so this will always return 0 correct?

Comment: Yes, from `1.546.23` to `32.645.1` (reverse) then find first '.' index

Comment: by the way it will not work if we would have more digits after last dot than one then it will retreive only records for where one simple digit at the end

Comment: but CHARINDEX - first argument should be what we looking for so dont have to be like this instead?: CHARINDEX(N'1', CAST(REVERSE(Nummer) as NVARCHAR(max)), 0) ?

Comment: note that at then end after last dot there could be more digits than 1

Comment: seems now its working. Why you put +2 for what it is?

Comment: `12.3356.2` For +1 Result `12.3356` For +2 Result `12.3356.`

Comment: so it means now whatever number of digits at the end it will get correct result right? Also whatever before that dot correct?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select *
from artikeltable 
where nummerfield like '12.3356.%' or nummerfield like '7.31.%';
```

Comment: yes but like has to be constructed based on result in 'final' table which you can see in my query. In this particural example i have two items in 'final' table(there could be more or less of course). Therefore LIKE statment has to be constructed as you wrote. But how to do it automaticly?